# semantic issue reference to cmtime is ambiguous

Tags: objective-c, ios7, linker-errors

I get this error **semantic issue reference to cmtime is ambiguous** whenever I am importing AVFoundtation

```
  #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

I guess the problem is with framework setting how can i resolve it

I tried with my friend's system same code is working there

Answer (score 1):

In order to use CMTime, you need **CoreMedia.framework**.

Framework CoreMedia.framework

Declared in 
CMAttachment.h
CMBase.h
CMBlockBuffer.h
CMBufferQueue.h
CMFormatDescription.h
CMSampleBuffer.h
CMTime.h

Comment: Thanks for the reply I've tried it doesn't work(I didn't used any CMTime in my Project)

Comment: I've responded to the statement 'semantic issue reference to cmtime is ambiguous.'  If you have a different issue, then please re-define it.